# print list and separate values by a comma comma and end with a dot

Tags: c

```
printf("Open lockers: ");
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(lockers); i++){
    if (lockers[i] == true){
        if(i == sizeof(lockers) - 1){
            printf(" %d.", i +1);
        }else
            printf(" %d,", i +1);
    } 
}
```

//This is what i got but it doesn't work for when i change list size

Comment: You also need to provide a [mcve] and tell us what output you get vs the output you want. You need to tell us at least what `lockers` is. Most likely `sizeof(lockers)` is not what you think it is.

Comment: lockers is list i want the program to work regardless of the size

Comment: Yes, obviously `lockers` is the list you are talking about, but how is `lockers` declared?

Comment: i dont think it matters but

Comment: bool lockers[N] = {false};

Comment: N is defined 100

Comment: please don't post clarifications in comments but [edit] your question instead. That's the way it works here. And yes, everything matters, if `lockers ` is declared as `bool *lockers;` then `sizeof(lockers)` is meaningless. Please read this before asking the next question: [ask].

Comment: I completed your code so I could compile and run it here and it appears to [work fine](https://www.ideone.com/WQhN8r). So the problem is somewhere in the part of your code you didn't show. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @Jabberwocky There is a problem with the above code.  A period would only be printed if the last `i` value corresponding to an open locker also happens to be the last element in the array.  If not, then the final dot would never be printed.

Comment: Don't include the comma in the format string of `printf(" %d,", i +1);`.

Comment: @Sterben Please _don't_ dramatically change your question like this. If you have issues with my answer, then comment _under my answer_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by maintaining some additional state which keeps track of whether or not it is the first open locker which needs to be reported.  And then, just print period outside the loop, only once.

```
printf("Open lockers: ");
int first = 1;

for (int i=0; i < sizeof(lockers); i++) {
    if (lockers[i] == true) {
        if (first == 0) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        else {
            first = 0;
        }

        printf("%d", i + 1);
    }
}
printf(".");
```

### Demo

Note: In the demo I replaced your `bool` lockers array with an `int` array.  But the rest of the logic remains the same.

Comment: no i tried but the out put is 
Open lockers:  1,,  2,,  4,,  6,.
instead of 1, 2, 4, 6.

Comment: @Sterben I have just tested this code and it seems to work.  [See the demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HkxXEn6cQ).

Comment: OH yeah sorry about that buddy i forgot to take out the comma  in printf("%d, ", i + 1);
i apologize thanks for your time

Comment: @Sterben copy/paste is helpful here ;-)

Comment: 100% my mistake sorry

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a variable like `pad` in this code:

```
const char *pad = "";
printf("Open lockers:");
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lockers); i++)
{
    if (lockers[i])
    {
        printf("%s %d", pad, i + 1);
        pad = ",";
    }
}
putchar('.');
```

Another variant is:

```
const char *pad = ":";
printf("Open lockers");
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lockers); i++)
{
    if (lockers[i])
    {
        printf("%s %d", pad, i + 1);
        pad = ",";
    }
}
putchar('.');
```

Note that `sizeof(lockers)` only works if `sizeof(lockers[0]) == 1`.  I left it because that's what you used, but I'd normally have a variable set to the maximum value and use that in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is probably wrong

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(lockers); i++){
    if (lockers[i] == true){
```

You do not show us, what `lockers` is. As you use it with an index it could be an array or a pointer to an array.

If `lockers` is an array, `sizeof` will result in the size in bytes. Unless the elements are of type `char`, you will end up accessing the array beyond its allocated memory.
You can get the number of elements using `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`.

```
int lockers[10];
```

With a definition like that you would access 40 integer elements whily you only have 10.

If `lockers` is a pointer to an array, `sizeof` will only result in the size of a pointer (probably 4 or 8 bytes) and you will not access all elements of your array where your pointer points to if the array has more elements than 4 or 8.

```
int *lockers = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```

With a definition like that you would only access 1 or 2 elements instead of 20.

Update:
In the comments I found the missing information. It would help a lot if you put it into the question instead of comments.

You are lucky, `sizeof(lockers[i])` is 1 which will work for your loop.